# PartImage: what is the cancelatio key?

Tags: partimage

[PartImage](http://www.partimage.org/Main_Page) is nice for partition image creation, but I can not find what is the **key to cancel** the operation when I made a mistake. For example:

[image: Can not cancel]

What key is that `[*` supposed to be?
I have not been able to find any help about on the PartImage [docs](http://www.partimage.org/Partimage-manual).

Comment: You can cancel it with * when it is started.

Comment: @taliezin, there are reasons for not waiting to the image creation/restore start, as long as it can overwrite some file(s) or partition(s) you did not want to. If I press `*` on the above image screen, all I get is the `*` character on the description field.